# Will HyperX Fury Black work together with HyperX Blu (both 4Gb 1600)?

Tags: memory, motherboard

I currently have this RAM stick `HyperX Blu 4GB 1600`. I need to buy another 4GB stick but they don't sell this model anymore. I found someone selling `HyperX Fury Black 4GB 1600`. I was wondering will this work just fine together? My motherboard is `ASUS H61M-E` btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That will be fine.

As a general rule, the make and model of RAM isn't important. As long as they're both the same module size and type (In this case, DDR3), the motherboard should handle the rest. Even if the stick is faster than the one you already have (Which in this case, it isn't), it should handle downclocking the faster one to match the speeds.

For completion, your motherboard spec states:

> 2 x DIMM, **Max. 16GB**, **DDR3**
>   2200(O.C.)/2133(O.C.)/2000(O.C.)/1866(O.C.)/**1600**/1333/1066 MHz
>   **Non-ECC, Un-buffered Memory**
>
> Dual Channel Memory Architecture
>
> - 1600MHz and higher frequency is supported by Intel® 3rd generation processors.
> - Refer to www.asus.com or user manual for the Memory QVL (Qualified Vendors Lists).
> - Due to OS limitation, when installing total memory of 4GB capacity or more, Windows® 32-bit operation system may only recognize less than 3GB. Install a 64-bit Windows® OS when you want to install 4GB or more memory on the motherboard.
> - Due to the CPU behavior, DDR3 2133/1866MHz memory module will run at DDR3 2000/1800MHz frequency as default.